# passing constant values to ng-model

Tags: html, angularjs

i am trying to pass a constant value to a label and trying to access it somewhere else.This is what i have tried

```
<label ng-model="alertID"> 1 </label>
```

and i am trying to access it in a controller by passing alertID to a function in controller.but i am getting "undefined" as alertID's value.Following is the function in controller

```
$scope.saveEventInfo = function(alertID){
   var id = alertID;
}
```

How do i get its value?I dont want to use ng-init

Comment: You'll probably get [this exception](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/nonassign) if you try to pass constant to `ng-model`.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-model` on a `label` doesn't make sense because it's not an input and therefore doesn't need two-way binding.

I'm guessing you just want to initialise the value like this:

```
<label ng-init="alertID = 1">{{ alertID }}</label>
```

`$scope.alertID` will now be `1` on your controller.

Comment: actually i am taking values from another function of controller

Comment: <label ng-model="alertID">id : {{eventData.alertEvent.id}}</label> this is what i am doing actually.So i cant use ng-init

Comment: I don't really know what you're trying to achieve with `ng-model="alertID"` in that case.

Comment: i am trying to set a value to label which i am getting from another function of the same controller